# Can't run code from "play button" - IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, properties, ide

I cannot run my Code from the play button anymore, it just shows "*nothing here*" (see image below). If I try it using the button in the top right corner, it works just fine, but it's really annoying to switch the files which I want to run every single time.

I really did not change any settings, it just happened out of nowhere. I already tried finding solutions on multiple forums, but couldn't find any answers either. My lucky guess would be that it has something to do with the ide.properties file?

Has anyone experienced something like this before? I'm using *IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.3* on *MacOS Catalina*.

[image: "Nothing here"]

Comment: Does it help to disable Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with a collegue using MacOS Catalina. Downgraded from 2019.3.1 to 2019.3 using the toolbox fixed the problem. After upgrading again to 2019.3.1 (and invalidating caches) we still didn't have the problem anymore. 
Not a real fix, but maybe it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Toolbox fixed the problem for me. Still don't have any clue why it was happening though.